# VBA code to create a task when sending emails

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

I would like to be able to create a task from a Sent email in Outlook at the time of sending. It is find if a button pops up asking me if I want a task, and I have to click Yes or No. I found the code below. But if I click Yes, it creates the task without me editing it. I just want the Task window to pop up with the email I sent populating it, but I want to add the dates etc. Can anyone help please?

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'Updated by Extendoffice 20181123
    Dim xYesNo As Integer
    Dim xPrompt As String
    Dim xTaskItem As TaskItem
    Dim xRecipient As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xPrompt = "Do you want to create a task for this message?"
    xYesNo = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Kutools for Outlook")
    Cancel = False
    If xYesNo = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Set xTaskItem = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    For Each Rcp In Item.Recipients
        If xRecipient = "" Then
            xRecipient = Rcp.Address
        Else
            xRecipient = xRecipient & vbCrLf & Rcp.Address
        End If
    Next Rcp
    xRecipient = xRecipient & vbCrLf & Item.Body
    With xTaskItem
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        .StartDate = Item.ReceivedTime
        .DueDate = Date + 3 + CDate("9:00:00 AM")
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderTime = Date + 2 + CDate("9:00:00 AM")
        .Body = xRecipient
        .Save
    End With
    Set xTaskItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Display` instead of `.Save`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Display` method if you need to show an Outlook inspector window for editing task properties:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'Updated by Extendoffice 20181123
    Dim xYesNo As Integer
    Dim xPrompt As String
    Dim xTaskItem As TaskItem
    Dim xRecipient As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xPrompt = "Do you want to create a task for this message?"
    xYesNo = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Kutools for Outlook")
    Cancel = False
    If xYesNo = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Set xTaskItem = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    For Each Rcp In Item.Recipients
        If xRecipient = "" Then
            xRecipient = Rcp.Address
        Else
            xRecipient = xRecipient & vbCrLf & Rcp.Address
        End If
    Next Rcp
    xRecipient = xRecipient & vbCrLf & Item.Body
    With xTaskItem
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        .StartDate = Item.ReceivedTime
        .DueDate = Date + 3 + CDate("9:00:00 AM")
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderTime = Date + 2 + CDate("9:00:00 AM")
        .Body = xRecipient
        .Display
    End With
    Set xTaskItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

In that case the original window should be closed and the email is sent out. But you will get the task item window opened for editing its properties. If you need to delay the send process until you are done with task properties editing process you may pass `true` to the `Display` method to stop the execution of the `ItemSend` event handler and wait until the dialog window is closed.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly. I haven't learnt VBA, just can fiddle with what others have done ;) On my To Do list!

Comment: Great news! Don't forget to mark the answer then.

Comment: Help! This has suddenly stopped working for some reason.... Is there a way to 'kickstart' it if not working?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? Just set a breakpoint in the code and go line-by-line tracking intermediate results.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start with that! I don't know enough to do it....

Comment: See [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)